# how to open a popup window from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to display a popup window from an iframe i have two jsp files
main.jsp

```
<form name="searchform">
        Search for :<input type="text" id="search"/>                
</form>
<iframe name="popup" src="popup.jsp" height="0" width="0" ></iframe>
```

and another file popup.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
    <link href="..css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script>

            $('#search',window.parent.document).keyup(function(){
                var text =$(this).val();
                if(text=="shine"){
                    alert("popup");                 

                }
            });     

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="popupDiv" class="popupDiv">            
            <table  border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr style="background-color: #F72C1B" class="orange1">
                    <td border="0" height="5%" width="30%"> 
                        &nbsp;Choose Options:</td>                  
                    <td border="0" height="5%" width="30%" align="right">
                        <a href="javascript:hideDIV()" style="text-decoration: none">
                         X </a> &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">popupdata</td>
                        </tr>
    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" class="orange1" onclick="selectedBoxes();"></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>                    
                </tr>               
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

how to show a popup window instead of the alert msg from iframe without modifying main.jsp.

```
Any ideas?
```

Comment: What popup? `#popupDiv`?

Comment: @putvande thanks for the replay can u elaborate,i have to display popupDiv from popup.jsp

Comment: Is that not just as simple as replacing `alert("popup");` with `$('#popupDiv').show();` or am I missing the point?

Comment: @putvande  $('#popupDiv').show(); displays the div within the iframe but i want it in parent window(main.jsp)

Comment: Than you need to replace the whole `#popupDiv` to your parent window with some jQuery (`window.parent.$('#somediv').append($('#popupDiv'))` or something like that.

Comment: @putvande ya,but main.jsp is something so sensitive page i am not allowed to modify it. is there any other way i can achieve the desired result

Comment: I thought that would be the problem. Than I don't think there is anything you can do really.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `window.open` instead of `alert`

Comment: Please explain your downvote, the OP states he wants a popup window, what would be better ?

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want such a popup.